# Why my html checkbox get print in in grey color in pdf file?

Tags: html, css

I am creating Html to pdf converter where the unchecked input checkbox are getting printed in grey color. How can I fix it to white.

```css
.check-box {
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="check-box">
```

Comment: `color` sets the text colour, it sounds like you might be trying to change the background colour?

Comment: Create a custom checkbox

Answer (score 0):

Some properties of form elements could not be modified exactly as one would like.

One solution would be to hide the checkbox element, and add an extra HTML element (a span element in this case) the play the role of the checkbox. This will change its state based on the checked attribute of the checkbox, when user clicks on the label assigned to that checkbox.

Keep in mind that the span should be always placed after the hidden input element, since the styling of the checkbox will be done based on its checked attribute.

```
<label for="my-checkbox" class="my-custom-label">
  Some label
  <input type="checkbox" id="my-checkbox" class="hidden" />
  <span>&check;</span>
</label>
```

[Fiddle provided here](https://jsfiddle.net/z34x0vfs/)